# 12.04, Slow load, VMWare Player

Tags: 12.04, vmware, disk, ssd

Everything, including booting, apt-get install, and web browser page load is snappy, but anything that requires random disk IO seems to be slow. The examples include: application launch, sudo command, etc. Any reason why this would happen?
I am using VMWare Play 4.0.4, 128GB SDD, 20GB allotted to the virtual disk. 
So far I tried both Hardware Acceleration Enabled/Disabled.
I also ran iozone test for disk IO speed, which seems to be reasonably fast.
I do no think I need to align my disk space as it should be managed by my primary OS, Windows 7. Could it be that this is VMWare issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I noticed that my BIOS had the multithreading setting, the Intel VT directed I/O and the Intel VT-x setting disabled. I enabled them and it was much faster. The vmplayer is not a hypervisor, so I surprised why the Intel virtualization settings should have made a difference.

Other things I did to improve the performance (thanks to suggestions on the Ubuntu forums) were to disable any 3D acceleration and using a lighter desktop (I used Xubuntu-desktop or Xfce4)